# Redirect to anchor in same page after form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have a website with a landing page, and at the bottom of the page I have a form. All I want to do is show a validation message and redirect the user to the form again so he can look the message without having to scroll.

The code is as follows (**it is on the same page**):

```
  //validation
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                     
          $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['name'])));

          if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]/", $name)) {
              $name_error = 'invalid name';
          }
         //i want to redirect as soon as the validation finishes
        header('Location: http://localhost/myweb/index.php#contact');
      } 

<form id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
  <input  type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
     <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

I have tried all of the following:

- Use of `window.location.href = 'index.php#contact';` in the button (`onclick`) and in the form (`onsubmit`)
- Use of the `header` in multiple parts of the code, also with `exit();`

**However**, and here is the key, I **do not** want to use another page of php only for validation (since I would need to use `session_start()` and I want to avoid cookies) AND and I **do not** want to use an AJAX XMLHttp Request.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using #contact in **form action** like this

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>#contact" method="POST">
```

Did you try this?